# What is a turn-down service?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-in-context, word-play

I'm sensing that it's not a real service but rather some specific play on words.

As shown in the image.
[image]

Comment: Very likely, this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turndown_service

Comment: @DamkerngT. I really googled the term before asking. Seriously. The article wasn't there before. I promise... (Must be me and my sleep depravation, I guess.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turndown service **is** a real service. In the hospitality industry, 'turndown service' refers to the practice of staff entering a guest's room and "turning down" the bed linen of the bed in the room, preparing the bed for use. A stereotype of the hospitality industry is that when staff come into your room, they invariably misplace your belongings (phone charger is mentioned) in the course of tidying up.

To 'turn down' something can also mean to reject or refuse something, so the last panel in the cartoon is a play on words - he is refusing (or turning down) the hotel's turndown service.